# Are encryption algorithms designed to hinder parallelization?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Are things like large memory requirements and constantly mutable state typically added to encryption alogrithms to hinder the ability of attackers to try multiple candidate keys simultaneously?  Also, is an encryption algorithm being less parallelizable often touted as an advantage of that algorithm?

Comment: "Also, is an encryption algorithm being less parallelizable often touted as an advantage of that algorithm?" No, because performance is a real concern with encryption algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a know ciphertext attack (the most likely one) the attacker would have access to the cipher text. He can make any number of copies of the cipher text now and run his bruteforce attack with multiple keys in parallel if he so chooses to.

In fact when specifically speaking of Block Ciphers (in symmetric encryption) the block cipher itself does not dictate parallelization as it always works with just one block in fact the Block Cipher or Stream Cipher "Mode" that it used can decide if the algorithm can be run in parallel on a given multi-block cipher text. For example Output Feedback "Mode" can be run in parallel for encryption but Cipher Block Chaining cannot be run in parallel. Either of these modes can be used with AES or other block ciphers that support these modes.

When it comes to asymmetric encryption like RSA or even Diffie-Hellman the idea is to never encrypt anything more than a single block in size. They are typically used to simply encrypt a symmetric key to perform more intensive encryption. So parallelization is less of a concern here.